# Winforms application with RavenDB has error: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ravendb

I got a very simple Winforms applications with a RavenDB database.  It has been working for a year until yesterday (Jan 19th, 2015).  It is now throwing the error: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage

The application is stored in my OneDrive folder - a quasi auto backup solution that seems to have been working.  Yesterday it went bang.  An excel file that I regularly use and located on OneDrive also had file access issues and I had to start using a new copy.

It seems to be related to an auto-update for Windows 8.1 that was applied over earlier.

I tried looking at permissions issues as suggested in other posts on this error.  They don't make any difference.

Here's the full stack trace.  Hopefully someone can help out.  Note I've removed folder names for privacy reasons.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage: C:\Users\...\Data\Data ---> Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentInvalidLogSequenceException: Timestamp in next log does not match expected
at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err)
at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetInit(JET_INSTANCE& instance)
at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs)
at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration, TransportState transportState)
at Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal()
at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize()
at ScanService.PostsDatabase.InitializeDocumentStore() in c:\...\PostsDatabase.cs:line 59
at ScanService.PostsDatabase.Retrieve(Int32 maxToReturn) in c:\...\PostsDatabase.cs:line 85
at ScanService.PostsTimer.Start() in c:\...\PostsTimer.cs:line 106
at ScanFormsUI.Scanner.StartPostsTimer() in c:\Users\...\Scanner.cs:line 72
at ScanFormsUI.Scanner.Scanner_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\...\ScanFormsUI\Scanner.cs:line 37
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ScanFormsUI
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/ScanFormsUI.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34230 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
ScanService
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/ScanService.EXE
----------------------------------------
System.Core
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Raven.Client.Lightweight
Assembly Version: 2.5.0.0
Win32 Version: 2.5.2851.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/Raven.Client.Lightweight.DLL
----------------------------------------
Raven.Client.Embedded
Assembly Version: 2.5.0.0
Win32 Version: 2.5.2851.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/../bin/Debug/Raven.Client.Embedded.DLL
----------------------------------------
Raven.Abstractions
Assembly Version: 2.5.0.0
Win32 Version: 2.5.2851.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/../bin/Debug/Raven.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Raven.Database
Assembly Version: 2.5.0.0
Win32 Version: 2.5.2851.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/.../bin/Debug/Raven.Database.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Composition
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.Composition/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 12.0.20806.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34212 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
Lucene.Net
Assembly Version: 3.0.3.0
Win32 Version: 3.0.3.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/Lucene.Net.DLL
----------------------------------------
Esent.Interop
Assembly Version: 1.7.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.7.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/Esent.Interop.DLL
----------------------------------------
Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS
Assembly Version: 3.0.3.0
Win32 Version: 3.0.3
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS.DLL
----------------------------------------
Spatial4n.Core.NTS
Assembly Version: 0.3.0.0
Win32 Version: 0.3.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/Spatial4n.Core.NTS.DLL
----------------------------------------
ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp
Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 5.2.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DLL
----------------------------------------
ICSharpCode.NRefactory
Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 5.2.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34230 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MetadataViewProxies_6961f4c8-f3b1-4967-a9af-abab52c56946
Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.Composition/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. It is a database it expects a consistent file system. I'm sure the data is hosed due to some transient fault of the storage.

Running [eseutil /r](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998074(v=EXCHG.65).aspx) may possibly salvage your database.

I love OneDrive but there's times I encounter faults even with regular office files, there's no way you can run a live database on it. If you want to pass around your data through OneDrive your best bet would be to export it and then import it.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Any idea where to get a safe download of this utility - the key work being 'safe' :)

Comment: I think it's in the Windows SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279